# Error: ResponseAuthBody{"error":"consent_required"}

Tags: rest

I am trying to create-envelope using rest Api and following the document provided by Docusogn.

I am using the code provided in the following [github](https://github.com/docusign/sfdc-recipe-rest-create-envelope).

I am getting the following error:

> ResponseAuthBody{"error":"consent_required"}
> ResponseAuthSystem.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because your domain not verified of email id.
So you need enable SSO for Your DocuSign organization. Then solved this issue
the integration key for individual consent

```
{Domain}/oauth/auth?response_type=code &scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=CLIENT_ID &redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
```

source:
https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-domains